# How to add a key in front of this indexed array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this php indexed array.

```
array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'good_time' => '2014-05-01 03:36:00',
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'good_time' => '2014-06-27 11:14:00',
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'good_time' => '2014-06-27 11:20:24'
    )
```

I want to add a key in front so that when I print it in json, it looks more meaningful.

```
'Time' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'good_time' => '2014-05-01 03:36:00',
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'good_time' => '2014-06-27 11:14:00',
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'id' => '6',
        'good_time' => '2014-06-27 11:20:24'
    )
)
```

How can this be done in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's this easy:

```
$newArray['Time'] = $otherArray;
```

or

```
$newArray = array('Time' => $otherArray); // now you can add other keys to $newArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your array is stored in `$a` variable. You can do

```
$a = array('Time' => $a);
```

Comment: @sgt Please try it. It gives exactly the desired result !

Comment: Upvoted for the reply. Thanks. Yours is also the right answer but I can only choose one answer, so I chose the answer who came in faster to be fair. Sorry.